# HibernateTemplate class cast exception

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am gettin below error. I am using Spring 3.2.2 and Hibernate 4. How can I create a new HibernateTemplate object?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder
```

I think this line gives error;

```
HibernateTemplate ht = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
```

Comment: HibernateTemplate is obsolete. You can't use it with Hibernate 4+.

Comment: Check your dependency hierarchy, I had this problems in other classes and it's because I had different spring-*.jars (for example spring-core-3.2.4 and spring-jdbc-3.1.3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code from org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate in your DAO implementation class imported packages.